# PIC 16F84 PCLATH Bit3+4 unnecessary for CALL/GOTO?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, pic, program-counter

I am trying to simulate the `PIC16F84` and now need to implement `PCL` / `PCLATH` registers.

The `PIC16F84` has 1K of Program memory.

The `PCL` is 8Bit wide, so in this case Bit 0 and 1 of `PCLATH` is used to switch between the four Pages each having a size of `256B`, am I right so far?

Based on this, I do not understand the following:

The [Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/35007b.pdf#page=41) states for a `GOTO`:

> The
> upper bits of PC are loaded from
> PCLATH<4:3>. GOTO is a two-
> cycle instruction.

But aren't the upper Bits of `PCLATH` too much? I mean there are only 4 Pages, each 256B, hence only bit 0 and 1 of `PCLATH` are needed. Or in other words - Bit 3 and 4 of `PCLATH` are always 0 ? Why would I then need to care about 'PCLATH' when performing a 'CALL' or 'GOTO' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIC16F84 has 13 bit program counter (PC). `GOTO` and `CALL` instructions have 11 bit address operands and the remaining 2 bits needs to come from somewhere, which is `PCLATH<4:3>`. As PIC16F84 has only 1K-word program memory, you don't need to care about `PCLATH` when using `GOTO` & `CALL`. Even having a non-zero random value won't affect the addressing, because datasheet states that:

> Accessing a location above the physically implemented address will
> cause a wraparound.

Still, it's best to keep `PCLATH<4:3>` bits clean for future compatibility to other PIC models that have bigger flash memories.

So, is `PCLATH` completely irrelevant for PIC16F84? **No.** There is one more situation where `PCLATH` is used: Modifiying `PCL`, the lower 8 bits of the PC. When `PCL` is modified, the remaining 5 bits of the PC comes from `PCLATH<4:0>`. Modifiying `PCL`, mostly by adding some values to it, used for creating `RETLW` tables, which can be used to embed arrays of constant values into flash memory. So, it's good idea to always have a proper & valid value in `PCLATH`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tagli , this solved the confusion.. So even when `PCL` is modified and the high bits of PC come from `PCLATH<4:0>` , the `PCLATH<4:3>` are actually zero and meant for future compatibility.. thats what confused us, that it has actually no impact due to it's program-memory size of 1K (Sure it's always better to have valid value in `PCLATH`)

Answer (score 1):

The Program Counter is 13 bits. The operand for `GOTO` is 11 bits, so for the remaining bits you want the two bits of `PCLATH` starting at `11-sizeof(PCL)`, ie `3`.

Here's a figure to illustrate this:

```
          12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
-------------------------------------------------
|--|--|--|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  PC (PCH:PCL)
-------------------------------------------------
          ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
          |  | 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
          |  | ---------------------------------- 
          |  | |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  GOTO operand
          |  | ----------------------------------
 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
-------------------------  
|--|--|--|  |  |  |  |  |  PCLATH
-------------------------
```

`PCH` (the upper byte of `PC`) is not directly accessible. Instead, you write to it through `PCLATH`. Hence why bit 0 of `PCLATH` lines up with bit 8 of `PC` in my diagram.

Comment: we have a Assembly code given which states: 
`movlw 1`
`movwf pclath`  
So `PCLATH` is now: 00001 -> Bit 3 & 4 are 0 but bit 0 is 1
There I don't see where PCLATH 3&4 are set to any value other than 0

Comment: Thanks @Michael ! concerning your figure: The GOTO Operand bit 8-10 overwrites then bit 0-2 of PCLATH, so Bit 3&4 are for page switching?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology used in PIC documentations, so I can't say whether "page switching" is the correct term. But the address will be formed by the 11-bit operand and bits 3&4 from `PCLATH`.

Comment: @totallynotatallno , `PCLATH<2:0>` bits are ignored by `GOTO` & `CALL` instructions. But the contents of `PCLATH` is not overwritten by these instructions and remains unmodified unless you manually change it.

Comment: Your ASCII art diagram doesn't line up perfectly.  The GOTO operand is one space left of where I think you want it.